# Relative Clauses or Appositives?

Tags: clauses, relative-clauses

Relative clauses usually involve the movement of an operator, either overt (wh-operator) or covert (silent operator)

```
The person who1 t1 killed Mary has been caught.
The dog Op1 that the cat clawed t1 is injured.
```

but the clauses below do not have any traces, which should mean that there is no movement of any operator:

```
The fact that he is a murderer disgusts me.
The rumour that he was a murderer was spread all over the media.
The finding that objects fall because of gravity shook the world.
```

Are the clausal complements of the nouns above relative clauses or appositives like in the sentences below?

```
John, the man who was caught, was sentenced to life imprisonment.
My sister, the judge who sentenced him, is responsible for it.
```

Comment: Neither: the subordinate clauses in your middle three examples are declarative content clauses. The subordinator "that", if present, is always clause initial.

Comment: @BillJ Understandable. They parallel regular complement clauses of verbs like "say", "think", "find", etc., but how are they linked to the constituents they complete? Are they syntactically complements of the noun (as opposed to relative clauses which are adjuncts) like how they are complements of the verb?

Comment: Yes, they are licensed by the head nouns. They can't be relative clauses  because there are no R elements anaphorically related to the head nouns— the subordinate clauses  simply give the content of "fact", "rumour" and "finding". And they can't be appositives because content clauses do not systematically yield appositives. I believe it is now accepted that appositives can only be NPs.

Comment: RCs are characterised by 'movement' (i.e. non-canonical word order) in English, but this is not universally true. For example, Chinese RCs do not have relative pronouns but have a relativiser (*de* in Mandarin), while other languages have internally-headed relative clauses, etc.

Comment: Yes, but the crucial property about RCs is they always contain an element -- actually present or understood -- that is **anaphorically related** to an antecedent from where it derives its interpretation. This is the basis for the term 'relative clause'.

Comment: Um I was responding to the OP... but anyway, I'm not sure I understand your definition. A relative clause is simply a clause that modifies a noun and restricts its referents in some way. That's the definition adopted in Keenan and Comrie (1977) and it's successful, so I think it should be stuck to in general. I think your definition would exclude Mandarin subject relative clauses and object relative clauses without a resumptive pronoun, for example.

Comment: This is a forum, and I'm talking about English. My definition is a standard widely-accepted one. The property of simply modifying nouns is way too broad as a definition since all non-finite clauses can also modify nouns. The property of containing an R element -- actually present or understood -- that is anaphorically related to an antecedent is crucial to the definition since it distinguishes relatives from the other two kinds of subordinate finite clause, i.e. content and comparative.

Comment: Movement in RCs does not occur when the anaphoric element in the RC is its subject. _That_ can occur, or a _wh_-word (well, **some** _wh_-words), but something that can be taken for an NP has to occur as subject of the finite verb in an RC. Hence _the man who(m)/that/⃠ I saw_, and _the man who/that came to dinner_ are all well-formed NPs, but not *_the man ⃠ came to dinner._

Comment: @BillJ H&P's definition surely works for English, but the OP opened the post with 'relative clauses...' rather than 'relative clauses in English...', so I figured it would be interesting and helpful to point out that RCs work differently in other languages. Do you know of any sources other than H&P that use the definition? The one I provided is the one I was taught as well as the only one I've seen in the literature (outside of H&P). (Not challenging you or anything, but H&P don't have in-text citations so I'm genuinely asking.)

Comment: You mentioned that non-finite clauses can also modify nouns. Do you mean phrases like 'the person trying to understand relative clauses'? I think that would count as an RC; Givón counts it, for example. As for the other two kinds of subordinate finite clauses, I might be missing something but I think this can be handled by the 'noun' part, since the other kinds of subordinate clause modify entire clauses or serve as complements to verbs etc.

Comment: No: In "The person _trying to understand relative clauses_", the sub clause is a gerund-participial clause. Gerund-participial clauses (and past-participials) are semantically similar to relatives: compare "The person _who was trying to understand relative clauses_", but they're not analysed as relatives since there is no possibility of them containing a relative phrase (cf. *_The person who trying to understand relative clauses_).

Comment: The two other kinds of non-finite clause, the past participial and the infinitival, can both modify nouns: "The guns _stolen in the break-in_ were recovered" / "We found a box _to keep the CDs in_". The latter is of course an infinitival relative clause

Comment: @WavesWashSands One things that is true for relative clauses, cross-linguistially (I believe), is that they modify other phrases. However, in the examples given by the OP, the clauses are not Modifiers but Complements. This rules them out in any language (so far as I'm aware) from being relative clauses. The strategy that English uses for relative clauses involves some element being missing from the clause involved or it being replaced by  a *wh-* word. This doesn't happen, of course, with OP's examples.

Comment: @WavesWashSands "A relative clause is simply a clause that modifies a noun and restricts its referents in some way" I don't think K&Comrie would ever have said that.For example, relative clauses don't modify nouns usually. More often they modify noun phrases, and sometimes other types of phrases as well, and clauses too. Also "non-defining" or "non-restrctive" relative clauses do not restrict the referents of that noun phrase (if that's what they're modifying in that instance).

Comment: @Araucaria I was paraphrasing from memory; sorry about the NP part. K&C did say they did not consider non-defining RCs.

Comment: @Araucaria (first comment; sorry for replying in the reverse way, I didn't see your first comment at first): I agree they aren't RCs; I was only trying to point out a small issue with the first sentence...

Comment: @Araucaria I'm not sure what you've added (or what it is you're trying to add) to this thread?

Comment: @BillJ I was just having niggle over the proposed K&Comrie definition of RCs, which didn't seem feasible to me - especially the noun part. (I think I was also under the (wildly mistaken I now understand) impression that WWS was analysing the content clauses as RCs.)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, right. I thought I'd got it all wrong for a moment. Incidentally, H&P make the point that integrated (defining) relatives modify nouns and nominals, but not full NPs.